# Ipywidgets FileUpload widget is not working with JupyterLab web app inside Docker

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

This is my first question on Stackoverflow.

I am using JupyterLab with Ipywidgets for a while now and wanted to put my work into a Docker container to share it. Unfortunately, I ran into an issue with the FileUpload widget from Ipywidgets which worked perfectly fine when JupyterLab was ran locally. With JupyterLab inside a Docker container I am just able to access my file system with this widget but I am unable to "pull" the content of a file into the widget. I am not really sure how the FileUpload widget is working. Is it sending "http" requests? What do I need to add to my Dockerfile to make this work?

[JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

[Ipywidgets FileUpload widget](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#File-Upload)

I am very new to Docker, so my Dockerfile is not optimized and sorted. And I needed to add a lot of things to my Dockerfile in order to make some JupyterLab extensions work.

## My Dockerfile:

`

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=python-3.8.8
ARG BASE_IMAGE=jupyter/scipy-notebook
FROM $BASE_IMAGE:$PYTHON_VERSION

ADD feral-1.10.1.jar .
ADD java ./java
ADD images ./images
ADD install.py .
ADD propertyFiles ./propertyFiles
ADD empty.properties .

COPY PropertyBuilderETHERNETnb.ipynb ./PropertyBuilderETHERNETnb.ipynb 

ENV TZ=Europe/Amsterdam \
    JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes
    
# Install yarn for handling npm packages
RUN npm install --global yarn
# Enable yarn global add:
ENV PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.yarn/bin"

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install jupyterlab==3.5.0 && \
    pip install ipywidgets &&\
    pip install colorama

USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get -qq --no-install-recommends install  openjdk-17-jdk && \
   python3 install.py
        
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64/
RUN echo "export PATH=$PATH" > /etc/environment

#Update and compile JupyterLab extensions?
RUN jupyter server extension disable nbclassic && \
     jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/celltags && \
     jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc && \
     jupyter labextension install @telamonian/theme-darcula && \
     jupyter labextension install jupyterlab_hidecode && \
     jupyter labextension update --all && \
     jupyter lab build 

CMD jupyter trust *PropertyBuilderETHERNETnb.ipynb && \
    jupyter lab --allow-root --NotebookApp.token=''
```

`

## Error, when I try to access the value of the widget after uploading:

[JupyterLab Error inside Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNHhu.png)

I already tried using Docker Bind Mounts to mount the container to my file system. Unfortunately this didn't have any impact. I expect that the widget is not working like this, I propably need to enable some "http" exchange access between the host and the Docker.

Thank you for the help. :)